# CS50 pset5 Load Function

Tags: c, load, trie, cs50

I'm having some trouble with the load section of pset5 on CS50, it would be great if someone could help. I'm trying to load a trie that reads from a dictionary (file fp below) and then iterates through the letters to create the trie.

I understand the concept of building a trie but I think I'm missing something with how the struct pointers are set up (hopefully I'm not way off the track with the code below).  I've tried to set up 'trap' to navigate through each stage of the try.

I'm currently getting a segmentation fault so not entirely sure where to go next.  Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
/** 
* Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
*/
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    //create word node and set root

    typedef struct node {
        bool is_word;
        struct node* children[27];
    } node;

    node* root = calloc(1, sizeof(root));
    root -> is_word = false;
    node* trav = root;

    //open small dictionary

    FILE* fp = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", dictionary);
        return false;
    } 

    //read characters one by one and write them to the trie

        for (int c = fgetc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp))
        {

            //set index using to lower.  Use a-1 to set ' to 0 and other letters 1-27

            int index = tolower(c)-('a'-1);

            //if new line (so end of word) set is_word to true and return trav to root)

            if (index == '\n')
            {
                trav->is_word = true;
                trav = root;
            }

            //if trav-> children is NULL then create a new node assign to next
            //and move trav to that position

            if (trav->children[index] == NULL)
            {
                node* next = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
                trav->children[index] = next;
                trav = next;
            }

            //else pointer must exist so move trav straight on

            else {
                trav = trav->children[index];
            }

    }

    fclose(fp);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did not read the question, just a blind suggestion, did you check [cs50.se]?

Comment: Yep, have watched all the videos and walkthroughs but still banging my head against the wall

Comment: which video? I'm talking about SE site..did you check the link in my comment?

Comment: 1) `node* root = calloc(1, sizeof(root));` --> `node* root = calloc(1, sizeof(*root));`

Comment: Gah, that should have been sizeof(node) not (root).  At least that fixed the segmentation fault :-)  Have a different error now but I'll try and crack on.  Thanks BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you set the size of array `children[]` to store 26 letters of the alphabet plus apostrophes. If so, when `fgetc(fp)` returns an apostrophe with an acsii code of 39 (I think), `index` will be set to -57, which is definitely not part of `trav->children`. That's probably where you're getting the segfault (or at least one of the places)
.

Hope this helps.